# TFS Branching - 2 Development branches

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, branching-and-merging, source-control-explorer

I currently use TFS and have the following structure.

A Dev line, a Mainline and a Release line in my TFS hierarchy. I use the same approach as detailed in the below link :

http://blog.tfsserver.com/a-straightforward-guide-to-branching/

(I plan on keep 2 or 3 most recent releases in the release line)

The mainline is the most recent version of code and a new release folder will be created to keep when the mainline code is tested and approved.

Currently in my dev line I have a dev branch which was created from the mainline.

This exsiting dev branch is currently being worked on by a developer where the changes will be ready in 4 weeks lets say.

I currently need to make urgent changes to the current version of code in production (Mainline) and I know these changes will take me 2 weeks to complete and test.

With this in mind, I obviously dont want to use the existing dev branch.

I cant make changes directly on the mainline so I am wondering if the following approach I am condsidering is the correct approach?

I am thinking I need to :

(1) Create a NEW Dev branch from the mainline.
    I would then have my original/existing dev branch and now a NEW dev branch.
    Both would be branched therefor from the same original code.

(2) Make my changes in the NEW dev branch

(3) Once I am happy with my changes, I would then merge my changes with the Mainline and release the    changes to production ( or selected customers) and merge my changes with the original Dev branch. 
    Then, when the original dev branch changes are completed 2 weeks after mine, it would be merged        with the mainline.

I am wondering is this the correct approach?
Can I merge changes from the NEW branch to the existing dev branch even if I didnt create my new branch from the existing/original dev branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you branch from the release branch, you can merge those changes back, regardless of any other branches.  They too can merge their changes, but they may have to go through a merge conflict resolution step if you have both worked on the same file.

When you merge your changes into the Mainline, then the dev branch can merge the changes down from Mainline into their code.

Another option, if you don't want to check in changes to mainline yet... if you're using a recent version of Visual Studio and TFS, then you can use shelvesets to merge code between branches.  However, only recent versions of VS/TFS do Shelveset merges on Unshelving.  Previously, it just copied whatever version of the file was shelved over any changes you might have made.

Comment: Hi Erik, thank for that. So as far as I can understand, there is no risk of losing changes from the original branch or no risk of overwriting changes from the newer dev branch as long as I perform the correct merge operations between branches. The merge conflict resolution steps would then allow me to get the latest version and merge the original dev changes to mainline. I am marking your answer as my accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to review the following methodology.

## Structure

[image]

### Main

Contains main source tree. Most recent development builds.

### Test

Branched from Main and used to isolate testing.

### Development

Branched from Main and used to isolate active development.

### Production

Branched from Main and contains the release candidate you are currently locking down prior to release. You work in this branch to prepare your software for release, while others continue to work in the Development branch working on new features.

### Maintenance

This folder contains branches you have already shipped but now need to maintain for customers. You use it to perform maintenance work. As soon as you release your software, you create a Maintenance* folder and move your Production branch into it. Use labels to mark pre-maintenance builds you may want to return to.

### Safe

This folder contains branches that you no longer maintain. When release is no longer eligible for updates, you move it from Maintenance container into Safe container.

## Stages

[image]

## Flow

Features each do its work in separate branches. When the teams are ready to integrate their work, they merge their branches into the Development branch.

When the builds from the Development branch are stable and ready to test, the teams merge the Development branch into the Test branch.

When QA accepts the builds, the team merges Test branch into the Main branch and creates Production branch from Main branch and let’s external pilot users to use it.

Once it is final, the team moves the Production branch to under Maintenance container and any further maintenance related to that release will be complete under that branch.

If release will no longer accepts maintenance, the team moves the branch from Maintenance to Safe container.

**BEFORE** you **WORK** on branches under Maintenance container **ALWAYS** make sure you **LABEL** it.

[image]

*Taken from [TFS Branching & Merging](http://goo.gl/KvBX1L)*